# How to get shadow effect in IE6

Tags: html, css

I am working on a HTML template. Using IE6 for testing not getting shadow like in all other browsers. 
IE6 doesn't support Box-shadow property.
So, How can I get Shadow Effect in working on IE6.

Please help...

Comment: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Comment: Are there still people using IE6?? Insane!

Comment: @mavili about 20% in china, sadly, see http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtobeexperiencedexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can emulate a CSS shadow using an IE6 DXImageTransform, for example

```
 filter:
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);
```

That snippet is from [this page](http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow) read it for more information on how.

Also [cbp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21966/cbp) suggested [this guide](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/) in the comments, after reading it, I think it's also a good resource, suggesting:

```
#box {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#ff0000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
zoom: 1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#ff0000);
```

Refer to this site:

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/